# Equivalent of "pthread_rwlock_timedrdlock()" and "pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock()" in MSVC/Windows

Tags: multithreading, posix, pthreads, visual-c++

What is the equivalent of following POSIX timed Reader/Writer locks in windows(MSVC)?

- pthread_rwlock_timedrdlock()
- pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/), which implements both functions (and the rest of pthreads) using the Win32 API. Its implementation of these functions should be enough to get you started. Or you could use it directly instead of the native Win32 thread and synchronization primitives.